# Interpretation of rounding the output of a quantum annealing solution for optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, annealing

I understand that quantum annealing approaches output a distribution of results of 0's and 1's for thequantum state.  I'm wondering if this can be interpreted in the following way:  For each qubit, we may compute a probability that the qubit will be a "1".  e.g. if we have 100 samples, and for the first qubit, 99 of them are 0, and the last one is 1, then the probability of the first qubit being 1 is 0.99.

If we agree that the interpretation is correct, then why is it not more common to use this as a rounding scheme for binary 0/1 optimization problems?  By intuition this would seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Any relevant papers/links regarding this would be most welcomed.

Comment: Output of a quantum annealer is string of classical zeros and ones. You run the annealer several times and then just pick up the best solution since quantum annealing is a heuristic. The approach is similar to any classical heuristic. I think it is not necessary to discuss probabilities of output strings as we are interested in the one that minimize the objective function.

Comment: Thanks @MartinVesely.  Then - what is the point of the correlation matrix returned by any quantum circuit, or quantum annealer?  In particular, if your measurements don't return all possible outcomes (since often the Hilbert space is huge), then can't you infer something about the states you haven't measured/observed?

Comment: I've heard it mentioned many times on this site that you can obtain a correlation matrix as output from QAOA (or any state that you can measure/sample).  It might help a lot if you could help me understand how that correlation matrix is obtained and what it means physically?

Comment: Could you please post a link where the correlation matrix is discussed in connection with QAOA?

Comment: Even better, examine this recent paper, especially section II.A.: https://arxiv.org/html/2307.05821v2.  I admit that I do not entirely understand their explanation, but it seems to suggest something related to the question I asked above.

Comment: Finally (and sorry to drag this out even more), if we think about a Bell state, there are hidden correlations that we don't observe them explicitly, but we can still reason about them. (e.g. see "Bell state correlations" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state)